# How to approach a coworker about mentoring

Tags: career-development, manager, mentoring

I have recently come to the conclusion that I want to approach manager positions within my current company. We are a large multi-national company, mainly positioned in Europe.

I am considering asking this one coworker, who is a manager - but not my direct manager, to be sort of my "mentor" in pursuing this goal. The reason I have chosen him, is because he made the jump inside the company from employee to manager. We have also worked together on a few projects, with him as project manager. On these projects I have always admired his personal and professional skills. On a personal level we also connect quite nicely.

We do not have any sort of official mentoring inside the company, which is why I said "mentor" with brackets above. Would it be considered odd/unprofessional, if I approached him about this? If no, how should I approach him about mentoring me  towards a manager postion?

Comment: I don't think its odd or unprofessional, but it may make your manager question why you didn't pick him/her, so I would give them a heads up and explain why so they aren't hurt by this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per se, it is just fine. Just start getting mentored by your colleague.

The only issue (and it can be big) is that you will ignore your direct manager - and that can be seen as an offense, even if nobody will admit it.

Depending on the details at the work place, you should have a discussion with your boss also. If your boss will not be on your side, you may need to have to approach manager positions in other companies.

Regardless of it being just a formality, or real stuff, you may ask you boss to be your mentor too. That way, you will not hurt his ego. You may discover a new friend in the process, too ;)